# does twig has any limitations

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Does twig have any kinda limitations?
since i have huge array and I am trying to render it with twig. And it just dies, I mean it does not generates template at all. i see just blank page, no error, nothing. I am using symfony2. I tried to change template engine to php and it's worked. So i am just interested is there are some kinda limitations. And why it does not gives me an error..

twig code:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

<h3>test</h3>

{% for group in results.groups %}
    {% for link in group.links %}
        <a href="{{link.link}}">{{link.link}}</a>
        <br>
        {% for key,keyword in link.keywords %}
            <span>{{keyword}} =>{{key}};</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for keyword in keywords %}
        <p>{{keyword}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

it's just to show results for client so i don't need speed or something. (I have like about 1k groups every group has about 50 links every link has 100 keywords ). If I remove the loop test becomes visible in template else I have blank page.

Comment: Does the object `link` have a method `__toString()`? You rely on it in `href="{{link}}"`.

Comment: typo sorry.. fixed, in my code i used {{link.link}} not {{link}}

Comment: What happens if you write `{% for group in results.groups %}test{% endfor %}`, removing both inner loops?

Comment: If you don't see any errors, then maybe your error reporting is disabled. A common case for what you're seeing is that the `memory_limit` is exceeded. Increase your error level, and look into the error logs to see the actual error. It's most certainly not a Twig problem.

Comment: well if it's not twig problem why php renders is perfectly? I increased memory_limit and turned on all errors, and plus it's app_dev.php so it should show errors any way.

Comment: {% for group in results.groups %}test{% endfor %} this one works, interesting..

Comment: Consider using array_slice in your controller to cut the number of groups down to say 10 and see what happens.